# Update rows in table 'A' with value 'Y', for matching records from a different table 'B"

Tags: sql

```
TESTDTA is the test database.
F41= First table
F42=Second table
```

Data from F41 TABLE

```
FLAG    STORE   NAME    NUMBER
S         1      A       A1
S         2      B       B2
S         3      C       C3
```

Data from F42 TABLE

```
STORE   NAME    NUMBER
1        A        A1
2        B        B2
3        C        C3
4        D        D4
```

I need to update values for the column "FLAG" in the tabel "F41" to value "P" if there is a matching record in the table "F42" .

I tried below SQL. But it has syntax error.

```
UPDATE TESTDATA.F41,TESTDATA.F42 SET F41.FLAG='P' 
WHERE F41.NAME=F42.NAME AND F41.NUMBER=F42.NUMBER
```

Can anyone help me to write this SQL?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: really depends on the version of SQL you need, what database is it running on?  Also, does the store need to match in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little cleaner

```
UPDATE F41 SET FLAG='P' 
 FROM  F41 A
 JOIN  F42 B on A.NAME=B.NAME AND A.NUMBER=B.NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

if your DBMS is Oracle and If by "matching records" you mean all column values in F41 match F42 then this might answer your problem:

DDL:

```
create tabLe F41
(
    FLAG        varchar2(10)
   ,STORE_x       number
   ,NAME_x        varchar2(10)
   ,NUMBER_x      varchar2(10)
);

create tabLe F42
(
    STORE_x       number
   ,NAME_x        varchar2(10)
   ,NUMBER_x      varchar2(10)
);
```

Note: Added _x to the Columns STORE, NAME, NUMBER because those are reserved words in some DBMS.

DML:

```
insert into F41 (FLAG, STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values ('S', 1, 'A', 'A1');
insert into F41 (FLAG, STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values ('S', 2, 'B', 'B2');
insert into F41 (FLAG, STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values ('S', 3, 'C', 'C3');

insert into F42 (STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values (1, 'A', 'A1');
insert into F42 (STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values (2, 'B', 'B2');
insert into F42 (STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values (3, 'C', 'C3');
insert into F42 (STORE_x, NAME_x, NUMBER_x) values (4, 'D', 'D4');
```

Update Statement Using Exists:

```
update  F41 t1
set     flag = 'P'
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT  1
                FROM    F42 t2
                WHERE   t2.STORE_X  = t1.STORE_X
                AND     t2.NAME_X   = t1.NAME_X
                AND     t2.NUMBER_X = t1.NUMBER_X);
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nothing more fancy than a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE TESTDATA.F41
    SET FLAG = 'P' 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TESTDATE.F42
                  WHERE F41.NAME = F42.NAME AND F41.NUMBER = F42.NUMBER
                 );
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Comment: This SQL worked Great..Thanks for helping me Gordon...Kudos Gordon

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TESTDATA.F41 SET F41.FLAG='P' 
FROM TESTDATA.F42
WHERE F41.NAME = F42.NAME AND F41.NUMBER = F42.NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TESTDATA.F41
SET FLAG = 'P' 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TESTDATE.F42
              WHERE F41.NAME = F42.NAME AND F41.NUMBER = F42.NUMBER
             );
```